# syntax of readmtx(fname,nrows,ncols,precision) in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to read a matrix from file using the following syntax in MATLAB . This matrix is of double numbers .

```
readmtx(fname,nrows,ncols,precision)
```

Here all the inputs are quite familiar to me . But I want to know about precision . The precision of int is 'int16'. What is the precision of double number?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/readmtx.html) states:

> Both binary and formatted data files can be read. If the file is binary, the precision argument is a format string recognized by fread. Repetition modifiers such as '40*char' are not supported. If the file is formatted, precision is a fscanf and sscanf-style format string of the form '%nX', where n is the number of characters within which the formatted data is found, and X is the conversion character such as 'g' or 'd'. Fortran-style double-precision output such as '0.0D00' can be read using a precision string such as '%nD', where n is the number of characters per element. This is an extension to the C-style format strings accepted by sscanf. Users unfamiliar with C should note that '%d' is preferred over '%i' for formatted integers. MATLAB syntax follows C in interpreting '%i' integers with leading zeros as octal. Formatted files with line endings need to provide the number of trailing bytes per row, which can be 1 for platforms with carriage returns or linefeed (Macintosh, UNIX®), or 2 for platforms with carriage returns and linefeeds (DOS).

In addition it is helpful to look at the table summary in the [`fread` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html#inputarg_precision):

[image]

Comment: @osimer Was this answer helpful to you? If so, please consider accepting it.